# Get JSON data from WebAPI & Load data into Store

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, extjs4.2

I am learning ExtJS-4.2, I was following their MVC tutorial...

I built my controller, view, model, store... My Store had hard-coded data. I have a working WebAPI for testing, which sends result in json format...

What the tutorial is talking about how to read from local file and send to an API,

**what i want to read from API and load my data into the store...**

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Productstore',
{
    extend   : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model    : 'AM.model.Productmodel',
    autoload : true,
    proxy    : {
            type   : 'AJAX',
            url    : 'localhost/mfw/api/products/all'
            //tutorial is no help any furthur from this point on
           }
});
```

My URL is `localhost/mfw/api/products/all`

and my returning json is

```
[{"ID":1,"Name":"aa","Category":"A","Price":200.00},
 {"ID":2,"Name":"bb","Category":"B","Price":200.00
 {"ID":3,"Name":"cc","Category":"C","Price":200.00},
 {"ID":4,"Name":"dd","Category":"D","Price":200.00},
 {"ID":5,"Name":"ee","Category":"E","Price":200.00},
 {"ID":6,"Name":"ee","Category":"F","Price":200.00}]
```

any help?

Comment: What issues are you getting? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the issue is there is no documentation, i am trying to cal a REST API to and load it's returned JSON data into my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your proxy type to 'rest' instead of 'Ajax'. More over mention your reader config. Did you map your json key with fields in model.

please refer sencha guide for more clarity.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/guide/data

Thanks

Comment: Have to agree the docs are basic and very lacking. Extjs looks like it is a great framework and from what I can tell that is true, but I am new to and from my experience so far it is very hard to get started with just basic data manipulation. Docs and examples to simple and not enough explanation of what is what and why or best practices and how.  Very frustrated!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delebash/PGggD/14/) showing a grid with your data.  One of the key things is the root property of the json reader.  Since your data does not have a root you can leave the root property out and it should work.  If you data is wrapped inside another field ie root field then specify root: 'myrootfield' in the reader.  So here is your proxy.  Also in your model specify the key field using idProperty in your case it is 'ID', I think extjs defaults to idProperty of 'id' lowercase so better to just specify it directly.

```
  proxy    : {
            type   : 'rest',
            url    : 'localhost/mfw/api/products/all'
           reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
           }
```

Comment: hey your answer is nice as well, but he came first